# Немного неровное выравнивание текста в кнопке по вертикали на разных устройствах

Tags: css

Наверняка многие сталкивались с этим. Речь идёт об обычной кнопке `<button>Text</button>` которой мы задаём какую то высоту `height: 30px;` и при этом этот текст на одних устройствах выравнивается чётко по вертикали (по середине), а на других немного съезжает вверх или вниз. Та же беда может быть и с браузерами. Если изменить высоту `height: 30px;` на пару пикселей, то эффект может на одних устройствах/браузерах пропасть, на других появиться.

Вот например: https://jsfiddle.net/un609g38/

```
<button>Text</button>
button {
  height: 30px;
  width: 90px;
}
```

Результат в Chrome, Firefox и IE (если задать одинаковый фон и границу разница в вертикальном выравнивании будет ещё более заметна):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Примеры и скриншоты? И вообще, а так ли это важно?

Comment: @AlexeyTen Ну как сказать, не приятно. Если есть какой то простой способ сделать лучше - почему бы им не воспользоваться.

Comment: По мне, либо вы рисуете кнопку целиком самостоятельно (Яндекс, Гугл) и тогда такой проблемы нет, либо оставляете системные (браузерные) кнопки и не паритесь. Потому что люди обычно используют один браузер и никогда не узнают, что в другом браузере текст сдвинут на пиксель.

Comment: Напомню ещё, что есть разные OS и мобильные браузеры в которых не только размер, но и шрифт будет другим.

Comment: @AlexeyTen Спасибо за наводку на гугл.

Comment: и лучше кнопку уже сделать не button, а каким-то div'ом. Браузеры рендерят (рисуют, видят) все по своему. Я уже молчу по поводу шрифтов, которые свою лепту вносят в положение символов относительно элемента.

Comment: Если смотреть визуально, то проблема заключается в шрифте, каждый браузер задает собственные стили по умолчанию, попробуйте их переопределить чтобы все смотрелось одинаково, задайте высоту и размер текста вместе с шрифтом и думаю проблема решится.

Answer (score 1):

display: flex должно помочь

```
.button{
  appearance: none;
  display: inline-flex; 
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Короче, помогает `line-height: 30px;` (подсмотрел у гугла).
Причём у гугла там цифры не совпадают (наверно что то совсем хитрое):

```
height: 36px;
line-height: 27px;
```

Ещё заметил (вообще мистика) `line-height` в CSS должен стоять строго после `font` (если таковое свойство имеется), иначе не работает, возможно `font` как будто его перекрывает почему то.

Comment: перекрывается потому что `font` это краткая запись, которая в себя включает также и `line-height` — `font: font-style font-variant font-weight font-size/line-height font-family;`.

Comment: @Sasha Omelchenko Так оно его перекрывает, даже если не указано, вот в чём мистика.

Comment: Если не указано, то берётся значение по умолчанию. Никакой мистики

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать через паддинги: Задаете внутренний отступ от текста кнопки. Не надо задавать высоту и ширину кнопки. Тут определил на глаз.

```
<button>Text</button>

button {
padding: 6px 31px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Задаете кнопке оригинальный класс и прописываете этому классу стили с `!important`

Comment: Никогда не используйте !important